# How do I set partial transparancy in GD with PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I am attempting to make a dynamic image with PHP, and I can't find out how to set partial transparency. It is very easy to make things either solid or fully transparent, but I have been unable to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [imagecolorallicatealpha()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php) There they create a transparent color circle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're creating your image with the imagecreatetruecolor function and that you're outputting the image as a PNG file....

You need to call the following methods to specify that the image must be generated as a 24-bit PNG before calling imagepng:

```
imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

Note that Internet Explorer 6 doesn't support 24-bit PNG files without the use of a CSS filter applied to the img tag.